# Right hand image disappears in browsers when zoomed

Tags: jquery, image, zooming

[JCSys.co.uk][1]Hi,
I'm having a problem on a a site that uses the JQuery cycle script to scroll three images in a header. When the browser is zoomed (90%- down)the third image on the right hand side (last in the scroll) disappears.
This doesnt happen in IE9 but does in IE8/IE10 and in Firefox. I Haven't tried in Chrome or Safari yet.

The site is   [1]: http://www.jcsys.co.uk

The css code for this scrolling header section is

```
#container #slidehowheaderbox .slideshow {
z-index: 2;
width: 332px;
position: relative;
left: 0px;
top: -220px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
}
#container #slidehowheaderbox .slideshow2 {
z-index: 2;
width: 334px;
position: relative;
left: 0px;
top: -220px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-right-style: solid;
border-left-style: solid;
border-right-color: #FFF;
border-left-color: #FFF;
}
#container #slidehowheaderbox .slideshow3 {
z-index: 2;
width: 333px;
position: relative;
left: 0px;
top: -220px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry,Do you mean the div containing these which is the #slideshowheaderbox?[code]#container #slidehowheaderbox {
 height: 193px;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 1000px;
}

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the third slideshow wraps when in zoomed view because of rounding applied by layout engines (they round element coordinates to avoid blurry edges).

I tried to fix your CSS but the positioning logic is way too messed up in my opinion.

Why are you using relative, floats and margins instead of a simple absolute positioning?

Comment: I couldnt get the images to position correctly with the overlay and the images to scroll otherwise with my limited knowledge